# Produce document with table-like structure

Tags: tables, paracol

I am trying to replicate a Word document which has a structure similar to the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{p{0.2\textwidth}|p{0.76\textwidth}}
  \hline
  \multirow[t]{3}*{Text} &
  Text\\
  \cline{2-2}&Text\\
  \cline{2-2}&Text\\
  %%%%%%%%%%%%
  \hline \multirow[t]{2}*{Text} &
  Text\\
  \cline{2-2}&Text\\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This works well when the table fits on a single page (though having to manually specify the span of the multirow is annoying). However, the content I have spans multiple pages. Even a single right "cell" might span several pages.
Currently, I am having to use a `longtable` and break the content manually into multiple cells but then I have to manually keep track of where the right splits are and how many right cells there are per every left cell.

I also thought about using `description` to achieve this structure, but then I don't know how to draw the lines.

Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE** after follow-up question.

This approach relies on the `paracol` package to write to two columns synchronously.

More importantly, it takes care of page breaks.

In this example, the `\switchcolumn` command will cause the text to go to the right column.

`\Rrule` will put a line in the right column.

`\Lrule` does two things: it draws a two-column line and executes `\switchcolumn*` to switch to the left column to start a synchronized column.

`\Frule` , used outside the paracol , will draw  a full width line.

[image: c]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{paracol}% added <<<<<<<<<

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % only for dummy text   

\newcommand{\Frule}{\vspace{-\topskip}\noindent\mbox{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5pt}}} % full width column rule
\newcommand{\Lrule}{\switchcolumn*\noindent\mbox{\rule{\dimexpr\columnwidth+0.5\columnsep}{0.5pt}}\par} %one column left rule
\newcommand{\Rrule}{\hspace{\dimexpr-0.5\columnsep-\parindent}\mbox{\rule{\dimexpr\columnwidth+0.5\columnsep}{0.5pt}}\par} % one column right rule


\begin{document}
    \setlength{\columnseprule}{0.5pt}  % width of the vertical rule
    \columnratio{0.3} % column ratio
    \setlength{\columnsep}{20pt}  % column separation
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    
    \Frule % full textwidth  rule when outside paracol
    \begin{paracol}{2}\sloppy   
        
        A. As any dedicated reader can clearly see, the Ideal of
        practical reason is a representation of, as far as I know, the things
        in themselves; as I have shown elsewhere, the phenomena should only be
        used as a canon for our understanding.
        
        \switchcolumn
        2. \kant[2]
        
        \Rrule %column wide rule
        3. \kant[3]
        
        \Lrule
        B. Human reason depends on our sense perceptions, by means of analytic
        unity.
        
        \switchcolumn% continue in the right column
        \Rrule %column wide rule
        4. \kant[11]
        \Rrule
        9. \kant[9]
        \Rrule
        11. \kant[1]
        \vspace*{\baselineskip}% add a blank line
    \end{paracol}
    \Frule % full textwidth  rule when outside paracol  
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: That’s great! Is there an easy way to have the the horizontal lines extend all the way to the vertical line? I know that this space is due to the margins in the column (which I very much want to keep) but I am wondering if one can temporarily change the margin for that line.

Comment: @Tohiko Please see the updated answer.

Comment: thank you very much. I wish I could upvote this more :) I just wanted to add that it seems that a new empty line before \Rrule is necessary.

Comment: @Tohiko It can be easily done, but it will not meet the vertical  line, To tell the truth I think it looks more elegant  when none of lines meet. Meanwhile add  `\vspace*{\baselineskip}` before `\end{paracol}`

Comment: @Tohiko If you want, it's easy to define a new environment that includes the top and bottom horizontal rulers plus the extra space.

Comment: thanks. Yes, that's what I plan to do. BTW, I just meant that to correctly use your method, `\Rrule` must be preceded by an empty line in the code (otherwise the horizontal line is slightly shifted). I think the solution is perfect as it is, I just wanted to clarify for posterity.